# Hypothesis Testing of Absolute Difference

Tags: hypothesis-testing, group-differences

Is a one-tailed hypothesis test of $|S_1-  S_2| = 0$ equivalent to a two-tailed hypothesis test of $S_1 =  S_2$? ($S_1$ and $S_2$ obviously represent a certain statistic of two samples.)

If not, where is the fundamental difference?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you have in mind for a test of the absolute value? // I am inclined to say that they are not equivalent, since $\vert S_1-S_2\vert=0$ is logically equivalent to $S_1=S_2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Dave. Let's suppose this is a test for difference in sample means such that $S_1$ is the sample mean of the first sample and $S_2$ the sample mean for the second sample. As you said, logically, $|S_1-S_2|=0$ is equivalent to $S_1=S_2$. So, wouldn't a one-sided test of $|S_1-S_2|=0$ be equivalent to a two-sided test of $S_1=S_2$ if we double the $p$-val in the former case (since we have now all the "extreme values" in one tail only)?

Comment: Your question has no meaning unless we interpret the $S_i$ as *parameters,* not statistics.  (A valid hypothesis is a statement about the underlying distribution, *not* about the data.)  With this understanding, the statement $|S_1 - S_2|=0$ is (obviously) identical to $S_1 = S_2.$ The implied alternative hypothesis, $|S_1-S_2|\ne 0,$ is equivalent to $S_1 \ne S_2:$ that's the alternative in a two-tailed test.  This is a purely a matter of notation and basic algebra--there is no fundamental difference.